# python mysql connector Fetchone returns none

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to connect mysql using Python mysql connector.

here's the code

```
from mysql.connector import connect as mysqlConnect, Error

myConn = mysqlConnect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password, port=port)
if myConn.is_connected():
    print('Connected to MySQL database')

cursor = myConn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.rowcount)
row = cursor.fetchone()
....
```

Problem is, even though cursor.rowcount is 3 but cursor.fetchone() returns None.

Please help me find what i have done wrong here

Comment: By doing `cursor.rowcount` you probably have already exhausted the iterator. Simply remove the line `print(cursor.rowcount)` and see what happens.

Comment: That was added later just to check. It isn't working without that too

Comment: Did my answer work? @mry